# My Player wont stick to the platform and I can't seem to fin a solution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make the player a child to the moving platform which is being moved by looking for waypoints and going to them. But when I make the player collide with the platform the collision enter is not detecting the player thus not making the player stay on it, it instead glides off.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndEXU.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movePlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    float rotSpeed;
    int current = 0;
    public float speed;
    float WPradius = 1;
    private GameObject target = null;
    private Vector3 offset;
    public GameObject Player;
CharacterController controller;

void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //This will make the player a child of the Obstacle
        controller.transform.parent = other.gameObject.transform;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    controller.transform.parent = null;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Vector3.Distance(waypoints[current].transform.position, transform.position) < WPradius)
    {

    current++;
        if (current >= waypoints.Length)
        {
            current = 0;
        }
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[current].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This will not make the player a child of the platform:

```cs
controller.transform.parent = other.gameObject.transform;
```

Because here `controller` is the CharacterController instance, and `other` refers to the player collider. So **they both refers to the player** transform in the end.

Replace it by something like

```
other.transform.parent = transform;
```

or

```
controller.transform.parent = transform;
```

*(Here, `transform` refers to the platform transform.)*

---

If the `OnTriggerEnter()` is not detecting, check if your collider has `isTrigger` enabled. Or change the method to `OnCollisionEnter()`.

If you are making a 2D game, switch these methods to the 2D version *(=> `OnCollisionEnter2D` or `OnTriggerEnter2D`)*.

Comment: Hi there, I have just given this a go and still doesn't seem to work I also made sure that the second box collider i have attached was isTrigger = true but still nothing